# my custom block (in admin panel) cache

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, static-block, block-cache

i create block in magento admin panel and i Calling template in it,the code is this (dynamic data)

> {{block type="core/template" template="catalog/category/sub.phtml"}}

My problem is here, my block cache by magento and it doesnt work correctly,
how can i disable cache for this Specified block?

Comment: try this code: {{block type="core/template" cache_lifetime="null" name="my_block_name" template="catalog/category/sub.phtml"}}

Comment: thanks but it didnt work